# Kivy/Python How to pass an object into another class?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to write a tennis app for a school project with Kivy/KivMD and python3 and I have a few issues that I cannot solve.

(1) In my main.py file, with the create_match method, I managed to create 2 objects, when pressing on the button, that I want to use for the next screen. The problem is that I don't know how to pass these 2 instances/objects into the GameScreen class where I want it. To make the thing work, I just manually added 2 other player objects in the GameScreen class, but that's not what I want. How can I do this?

(2) In the main.kv file, I'd like to modify the InputScreen class in another file (input_screen.kv, like I did with game_screen.kv). How can I do that without breaking everything? Because the InputScreen contains a button (CreateButton) that relies on the ScreenManager which is in the main.kv file, so I'm a bit stuck...

These are my 2 main issues, I know it's a bit long to read, but I'd really appreciate if someone could explain to me how to pull this off. I am not showing you the Player class, because there is no issue with it, it just counts the points of each player according to tennis rules.

P.S I know I should show minimal code, but it's hard with GUI...

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

from App.score import Player


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class InputScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CreateButton(MDRectangleFlatButton, Player):

    def create_match(self):
        player1 = Player(self.player1_name)
        player2 = Player(self.player2_name)


class GameScreen(Screen, Player):

    player1 = Player('Player1')  # I want that the name is given by the user
    player2 = Player('Player2')


class TennisApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TennisApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
#:include game_screen.kv

ScreenManager:
    id: manager

    HomeScreen:
        name: "home_screen"
        id: home_screen
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Create a match"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            on_release: manager.current = "input_screen"

    InputScreen:
        name : "input_screen"
        id: input_screen
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint: .6, .6
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8}
            spacing: dp(20)
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDTextField:
                id: entry1
                hint_text: "First player name"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            MDTextField:
                id: entry2
                hint_text: "Second player name"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        CreateButton:
            text: "Create a match"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .2}
            on_release: manager.current = "game_screen"
            on_release: self.create_match()
            player1_name: entry1.text
            player2_name: entry2.text

    GameScreen:
```

**game_screen.kv**

```
<GameScreen>:
    name: "game_screen"
    id: second_screen
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        adaptive_height: True
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': .9}
            adaptive_height: True
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            MDLabel:
                text: "Players"
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                text: "Points"
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                text: "Games"
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                text: "Sets"
                halign: 'center'

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': .8}
            adaptive_height: True

            MDLabel:
                text: root.player1.get_name()
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                id: points_label1
                text: '0'
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                id: games_label1
                text: "0"
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                id: sets_label1
                text: "0"
                halign: 'center'
        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': .7}

            MDLabel:
                text: root.player2.get_name()
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                id: points_label2
                text: "0"
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                id: games_label2
                text: "0"
                halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
                id: sets_label2
                text: "0"
                halign: 'center'

    MDRectangleFlatButton:  # I know this repetition is ugly, I will change it later
        text: "{} wins the point".format(root.player1.get_name())
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'center_y':.2}
        on_press: root.player1.points_win(root.player2)
        on_release: points_label1.text = root.player1.get_points_amount()
        on_release: points_label2.text = root.player2.get_points_amount()
        on_release: games_label2.text = root.player2.get_games_amount()
        on_release: games_label1.text = root.player1.get_games_amount()
        on_release: sets_label2.text = root.player2.get_sets_amount()
        on_release: sets_label1.text = root.player1.get_sets_amount()
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "{} wins the point".format(root.player2.get_name())
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .7, 'center_y':.2}
        on_press: root.player2.points_win(root.player1)
        on_release: points_label2.text = root.player2.get_points_amount()
        on_release: points_label1.text = root.player1.get_points_amount()
        on_release: games_label2.text = root.player2.get_games_amount()
        on_release: games_label1.text = root.player1.get_games_amount()
        on_release: sets_label2.text = root.player2.get_sets_amount()
        on_release: sets_label1.text = root.player1.get_sets_amount()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you dont need to pass the class into another class in order to used it there. Classes are like blueprints where the basic features like methods or attributes are stored. To fill the structure with life you have to create an instance of the class, where can pass variables into the class to make more unique or to fill your needs. What you are doing is to make the class GameScreen inherint the class Player. This adds the methods and attributes of the Player class to the Gamescreen class which is not really neccessary. This is a huge topic itself and there are a lot of great explanations out there, if you want to know more just start to search for it.

**Back to your questions.** You wanted to know how to pass things into a class. I will give you a short example where I created two players based on a Player class and pass them into the Arena class which is the screen where the match happens.

When you define a class you can also define a init method. this method takes all the attributes you pass into the class when creating an instance. In this case I pass a players_list into the arena class which is what you wanted to do. Within your class you can do something with your passed objects. I decided to name the attribute players and then added them to the playground. I hope it helps you with your project. Just keep going and you will get this to work, I am sure.

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Window.size = 600, 400

class Player(Button):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.text = self.name
        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.size = Window.width, Window.height*0.1
        self.on_press = self.hit_the_ball

    def hit_the_ball(self):
        self.parent.parent.field.text = self.text + " played his turn!"

class Arena(Screen):
    def __init__(self, players, **kwargs):
        super(Arena, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.playground = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint=(None, None), size=Window.size)

        self.field = Label(text="", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height*0.8))

        self.playground.add_widget(players[0])
        self.playground.add_widget(self.field)
        self.playground.add_widget(players[1])

        self.add_widget(self.playground)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        player1 = Player(name="Player1")
        player2 = Player(name="Player2")

        players_list = (player1, player2)

        arena = Arena(players_list)
        WMan  = ScreenManager()
        WMan.add_widget(arena)

        return WMan


MyApp().run()
```